# What are the benefits of using a Single-Node Docker Swarm instead of Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What are the actual user-noticeable differences between a stack run with Docker Compose, vs that same stack run from a single host in Swarm mode?

In other words, what are the concrete benefits, if any, of using Swarm mode with only one node vs. Docker Compose?

**Research**

1. I have seen [other SO answers trying to tackle this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792854/docker-swarm-vs-docker-compose-on-single-host-in-production), but lack the depth I am seeking (see related info in [the Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)).
2. [This answer seems wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45993497/3006096), as [Compose supports deploy keys](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/deploy/#resources).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-swarm vs.docker-compose on single host in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792854/docker-swarm-vs-docker-compose-on-single-host-in-production)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between Docker compose and Swarm is that the first is a way to connect multiple containers together while the second is an orchestrator tool.

This implies that, even in a single cluster scenario, they will be different in particular in relation to the following points:

- Healthcheck: in Swarm there are periodical healthchecks and when a container fails the healthcheck repeatedly it will be killed and restarted while on docker compose you can can just set the restart policy in case the container crash
- Deploy: Swarm has options for controlling how you replace containers during an update such as rolling update that rolls back if there’s a problem, while docker compose not
- Extra features: Swarm has additional features to manage secrets and configs
- Extend the cluster: When you want to add nodes to your cluster, with Swarm you just need to add more nodes to the master node, while on docker compose you have to re-deploy it
- Compatibility: Docker and Swarm are the same daemon, so there are no issue related to versions compatibility
- Installation: with Swarm you have no need to install additional package/plugin, such as docker compose plugin or docker-compose for older versions
- Ease: Swarm only takes a single command (`docker swarm init`) to create a Swarm

It saves you from needing to manually install/update docker-compose on that server. Docker engine is installable and updatable via common Linux package managers (apt, yum) via https://store.docker.com but docker-compose is not.

Of course in a multiple-nodes cluster configuration you have more benefits from using an orchestration tool like Docker Swarm.

Comment: Thanks! I found this awesome post in the meantime: https://devopstuto-docker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docker_swarm/articles/2018/01__2018_10_17/01__2018_10_17.html. Want to add these extra benefits to your answer?

Comment: Alez: Where in the docs did you find the behavior in your first bullet (i.e. that if the container is not healthy it is automatically restarted)? Thanks!

Comment: In your post, it's bullet number 5: "docker run and docker-compose won’t re-create containers that failed a built-in healthcheck".
Sure, I'll give a look of the article and add additional benefits, even if the major ones are already in my answer.

Comment: Do you know where in the official Docs I can find info on that though (the health checks and fault tolerance of Swarm vs Compose, I mean)? I have been poking around for a few hours with no success.

Comment: The blog post seems to be from 2018. A **lot** has changed since then making some points out of date. E.g. `docker compose` is now much more integrated with the `docker` deamon as a plugin, so no more manual installation outside the package manager required and thus no more version incompatibilities.

Comment: @Magnus I couldn't find either

Comment: @acran thanks for the precisation. I slightly edit the point related to the installation to be more precise. Other than this, all the listed points seems to me updated with the state of the art. If not, please let me know.